# Replace text with str_replace with array

Tags: php, str-replace

Well, I would make it easier to add smileys and the code it should be replaced with a bit easier, So insted of creating 2 arrays, I would like to only have one.
So this is a example how I wanted it.
$Smileys = array(":D" => "");

So instead of using it like
$Smileys = array(":D");
$SmileyReplace = array("");
 But is it possible at all?
I can't seem to find something on Google that helps.

My new code that I wanted to use and the old.
New:

```
function fixSmileys($Data) {
        $Smileys = array(
        ":D" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/grin.png" title=":D" alt=":D"/>',
        ":)" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/smile.png" title=":)" alt=":)"/>',
        ":P" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/tongue.png" title=":P" alt=":P"/>',
        ":S" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/confused.png" title=":S" alt=":S"/>',
        ":'(" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/cry.png" title=":'."'".'(" alt=":Cry:"/>',
        ":$" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/embarrassed.png" title=":$" alt=":$"/>',
        ":(" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/frown.png" title=":(" alt=":("/>',
        ":@" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/mad.png" title=":@" alt=":@"/>',
        ";)" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/wink.png" title=";)" alt=";)"/>',
        "B)" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/cool.png" title="B)" alt="B)"/>',
        ":|" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/neutral.png" title=":|" alt=":|"/>',
        ":lol:" => '( ?° ?? ?°)',
        ":derp:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/derp.png" title=":derp:" alt=":derp:"/>',
        ";D" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/awesome.png" title=";D" alt=";D"/>',
        ":troll:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/troll.png" title=":troll:" alt=":troll:"/>',
        ":spin:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/abspin.gif" title=":spin:" alt=":spin:"/>',
        ":love:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/heart.png" title=":love:" alt=":love:"/>',
        ":sick:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/sick.png" title=":lol:" alt=":sick:"/>',
        ":O_O:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/sawut.png" title=":O_O:" alt=":O_O:"/>',
        ":bath:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/bath-time.png" title=":bath:" alt=":bath:"/>',
        ":socks:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/socks.png" title=":socks:" alt=":socks:"/>',
        ":boss:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/SuitBozzsmiley.png" title=":boss:" alt=":boss:"/>',
        ":potato:" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/potatoes.png" title=":potato:" alt=":potato:"/>');
        return $Smileys[$Data];
}
```

And the old code that I currenty use that uses only str_replace and alot of lines.

```
function fixSmileys($Data) {
        $xCommentx = $Data;
    $xCommentx1 = str_replace(":D", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/grin.png" title=":D" alt=":D"/>', $xCommentx);
    $xCommentx2 = str_replace(":)", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/smile.png" title=":)" alt=":)"/>', $xCommentx1);
    $xCommentx3 = str_replace(":P", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/tongue.png" title=":P" alt=":P"/>', $xCommentx2);
    $xCommentx4 = str_replace(":S", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/confused.png" title=":S" alt=":S"/>', $xCommentx3);
    $xCommentx5 = str_replace(":'(", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/cry.png" title=":'."'".'(" alt=":Cry:"/>', $xCommentx4);
    $xCommentx6 = str_replace(":$", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/embarrassed.png" title=":$" alt=":$"/>', $xCommentx5);
    $xCommentx7 = str_replace(":(", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/frown.png" title=":(" alt=":("/>', $xCommentx6);
    $xCommentx8 = str_replace(":@", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/mad.png" title=":@" alt=":@"/>', $xCommentx7);
    $xCommentx9 = str_replace(";)", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/wink.png" title=";)" alt=";)"/>', $xCommentx8);
    $xCommentx10 = str_replace("B)", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/cool.png" title="B)" alt="B)"/>', $xCommentx9);
    $xCommentx11 = str_replace(":lol:", '( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)', $xCommentx10);
    $xCommentx12 = str_replace(":derp:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/derp.png" title=":derp:" alt=":derp:"/>', $xCommentx11);
    $xCommentx13 = str_replace(";D", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/awesome.png" title=";D" alt=";D"/>', $xCommentx12);
    $xCommentx14 = str_replace(":troll:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/troll.png" title=":troll:" alt=":troll:"/>', $xCommentx13);
    $xCommentx15 = str_replace(":approve:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/approved.png" title=":approve:" alt=":approve:"/>', $xCommentx14);
    $xCommentx16 = str_replace(":lolol:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/lolol.png" title=":brohoof:" alt=":brohoof:"/>', $xCommentx15);
    $xCommentx17 = str_replace(":asdf:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/asdf.png" title=":facehoof:" alt=":facehoof:"/>', $xCommentx16);
    $xCommentx18 = str_replace(":spin:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/abspin.gif" title=":spin:" alt=":spin:"/>', $xCommentx17);
    $xCommentx19 = str_replace(":love:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/heart.png" title=":love:" alt=":love:"/>', $xCommentx18);
    $xCommentx20 = str_replace(":sick:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/sick.png" title=":lol:" alt=":sick:"/>', $xCommentx19);
    $xCommentx21 = str_replace(":O_O:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/sawut.png" title=":O_O:" alt=":O_O:"/>', $xCommentx20);
    $xCommentx22 = str_replace(":bath:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/bath-time.png" title=":bath:" alt=":bath:"/>', $xCommentx21);
    $xCommentx23 = str_replace(":socks:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/socks.png" title=":socks:" alt=":socks:"/>', $xCommentx22);
    $xCommentx24 = str_replace(":boss:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/SuitBozzsmiley.png" title=":boss:" alt=":boss:"/>', $xCommentx23);
    $xCommentx25 = str_replace(":potato:", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/potatoes.png" title=":potato:" alt=":potato:"/>', $xCommentx24);
    $xCommentxFinal = str_replace(":|", '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/neutral.png" title=":|" alt=":|"/>', $xCommentx25);
    return $xCommentxFinal;
}
```

The currenty code works as follow, The $Data that is being feeded contains like "Hello world :D" So it goes thru all the str_replaces until it finds the match and replaces it with a html code.
But I would just like to have it like the New, but useless nonworking code.
The reason I would like have it like that is to have it easier to add smileys to the site.

Comment: [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) - this has also the benefit of being free of the side-effects you have with `str_replace`. - p.s. learn how to use google, especially if you search for something technical.

Comment: since you have an array `$Smileys`, can't you just get the input string, then iterate through the $Smileys and run a str_replace? would be much easier.

Comment: Why are you using so much `str_replace` why not assign the all with array and just do one str_replace?

Comment: I bet your first function is faster than the second function!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple way of doing this using `strtr`. See documentation and examples http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use it in one function by spliting the array into two using buildin functions eg:

```
...
return str_replace(array_keys($Smileys), array_values($Smileys), $Data)
```

**EDIT:** Keep in mind that those functions do a copy of the array so propably there are better solutions than spliting one array into two ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you. :)

```
function fixSmileys($Data,$direction) {
        $Smileys = array(
        ":D" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/grin.png" title=":D" alt=":D"/>',
        ":)" => '<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/smile.png" title=":)" alt=":)"/>');

    foreach($Smileys as $key=>$value){//echo $key;
      if($direction==1){$Data=str_replace($key,$value,$Data);}
      elseif($direction==2){$Data=str_replace($value,$key,$Data);}
    }

        return $Data;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
echo fixSmileys("hello there :D",1)."<br>".fixSmileys('<img src="/application/modules/Chat/externals/images/smilies/grin.png" title=":D" alt=":D"/>',2);
```

Comment: 25 * `str_replace` call not very performance friendly

Comment: yes i know, but its working :)

Comment: So you know and do nothing to improve it? Not very good attitiude for a programmer ;)

Comment: i make it work like it should then in free time i optimize things